# C++, C++/CLI, C#間のプロパティ変更通知

Tags: c#, c++, wpf

現在、C++, C++/CLI, C#(WPF)を用いて画像処理を行うプログラムを試験的に作成しています。

画像処理をメインで行うのはC++プロジェクトで、これはスタティックライブラリです。
それをC++/CLIでラップし、ダイナミックライブラリにしています。
WPFプロジェクトでC++/CLIのdllを読み込み、処理された画像を表示させたいと思っています。

この時、画像やその他のプロパティが複数あったとして
それらの変更をC++プロジェクトからWPFプロジェクトまで伝番させる必要があります。
しかし、C++とC++/CLI間、C++/CLI, C#間でのプロパティ変更通知を
どの様に実装すればよいのかわかりません。

どういった手法を取るべきか、そもそもそういったやり方ではないのか
参考になるWebページなどをご存じでしたらご教示いただければと思います。

---

<解決>
回答で紹介してもらったサイトを参考に変更通知を実装しました。
https://github.com/Nao05215/CamTest

Comment: 実現したいのは「C# → C++/CLI → C++コードで保持する何らかの値(≒プロパティ)を変更すると、プロパティ変更通知として事前設定したC#側デリゲートが呼ばれる」というイメージでしょうか？部分的な疑似コードで構わないので、C#側／C++側のコードをイメージできるような例を追記されたほうが良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ここ、参考になりませんか？C++/CLIは使ってないみたいですが。
C#からC++のDLLへデリゲートを渡し、DLL側でコールバック
https://qiita.com/yz2cm/items/8bc26f789c3308799aa9